Lost Wifi || could not recognise Tp-Link Archer T9Uh Ac1900
I recently made a update and my current kernal version is "Linux 6.8.0-45-generic x86_64"
The Tp-Link Archer T9Uh Ac1900 was working fine before the update, I restarted post update and the system is not showing up the wifi, can someone please help !!

You've not told us what Ubuntu product/release you're using; you mention a kernel which is used by different Ubuntu releases; for one of those switching kernel stack maybe an easy workaround (multiple kernel stacks can be installed) for example.

I suspect your Tp-Link Archer T9Uh Ac1900[RTL8814AU] driver is not working for the new kernel. (I have also seen this device reported as using RTL8821AU but it is also on the site below).
Try the driver here. I think yours is on this. (8814au and 8821au)?
https://github.com/morrownr
Compatible Kernels
Kernels: 4.19 - 5.2 (Realtek)
Kernels: 5.3 - 6.9 (community support)

Use dkms status to identify the device driver (RTL8814AU) for each succesfully built kernel. Your original driver source could/will have an uninstall to uninstall it. If not then you could uninstall it as follows: -
Typical output of dkms status
rtl8814au/X.XX.X.X, 6.8.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8814au/X.XX.X.X, 6.8.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed

Typical removal from the dkms. If it is removed it should also stop the driver installing but you might have to reboot to achieve this. You need to use your details of the driver you have installed but here are are some examples. (Note: Only uninstall from non-active or broken driver kernels.)
dkms remove rtl8814au/x.x.x.x --all
dkms remove rtl8814au/x.x.x.x -k  6.8.0-45-generic -a x86_64

Installation
Open a gnome-terminal
sudo apt install -y build-essential dkms git iw #Tools needed
mkdir -p ~/src #make a directory to place the sources
cd ~/src #move to directory
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8814au.git  #download sources
cd ~/src/8814au  #Move into sources
sudo ./install-driver.sh  #(Note to remove it run remove-driver.sh).
If you are running secure boot and you have not installed a mokkey the driver will not get signed so it will not run. The instructions on the site do give some advice regarding this.
I think it is a good idea to reboot before you starting testing.

Building module:
cleaning build area...
./dkms-make.sh....(bad exit status: 2
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814au: 5.8.5.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814au/5.8.5.1/build/make.log for more information.
Command exited with non-zero status 10
Compile time: 65.00 seconds
An error occurred. dkms build error:  10
Please report this error.
Please copy all screen output and paste it into the problem report.
Cannot run the Install-driver.sh command
Am I missing something.

Append the make.log to your original question. (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814au/5.8.5.1/build/make.log) On my machine its at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814au/5.8.5.1/6.8.0-47-generic/x86_64/log/make.log

I had a thought after the one above. Counter-intuitive as it is you run ./install-driver.sh (as per the instructions) to install the driver into the dkms and not ./dkms-make.sh That latter file is for internal use. If you edit it there is a comment at the start to this effect. (This caught me when I first installed it.)
